# bootstrap 4 offset-lg not working in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular

In my Angular application, I'm using bootstrap 4 (version 4.5). I just only imported two file in my slyle.css file

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

But while I'm applying **offset-lg-7** it's not working.

I'm seeing in my developer tool my class **offset-lg-7** used as redundant

```
<pre>
@media (min-width: 992px)                                                             _grid.scss:56
.offset-lg-7 {
  margin-left: 58.333333%; //code becomes redundant
}
</pre>
```

And how this **_grid.scss** file used actually I don't have any idea.
I can use this by making my classes as important.But I'm looking for permanent solution.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Dalim, the idea of write `offset-lg-7`is write in the .html -offset-lg-7 has yet the min-width. Some like `<div class=" offset-6-md offset-lg-7">..</div>` get the offset of 50% with if greater (or equal) than 768px and of 58.33% if the width if greater (or equal) than 992px

Comment: Dear brother @Eliseo, I have the idea of offset and margin left but I would like to know why this is not working in my html. And also I would like to know how **_grid.scss** called in html rather than **bootstrap.min.css**